# Check function going into infinite loop and segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, infinite-loop

```
void InputStatisticalData() 
{
    //variables declaration

    cout << "\n[Here to take in data]" << endl;

   //cin data

    while (exit == false)
    {
        cout << "Entered Loop" << endl;//for troubleshooting purpose
        cout << "CountCheck: " << countcheck << endl;//for troubleshooting purpose

        if (!Vector.empty())
        {
            cout << "Entered Vector check IF" << endl;//for troubleshooting purpose

            if (condition)//checks if data has any duplicates
            {
                cout << "\nData already exist, please enter a new set of data." << endl;
                break;
            }

            else
            {   
                cout << "Entered countcheck++" << endl;//for troubleshooting purpose
                countcheck++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //stores data
            exit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Hi guys, above is my function to take in some data and store them into an object before storing into a vector. Everything works fine, therefore i decided to do some validation checking for the function. 1 of it is to check if the data keyed in, is it already been keyed in before.

I can store the data once and that's it, once i attempt to store it again, it will go into an infinite loop and give me a segmentation fault. I have been trying to solve it for a week but to no avail.

Another infinite loop is the **cin.fail**. It goes into an infinite loop as well if a wrong input is detected.

Thanks for taking your time to take a look.

Lol, why keep down-voting my questions, there's a question and a solution, it's suppose to help others, so stop down-voting and upvote it

Comment: Store again the same data? What was your output before giving segfault ?

Comment: nothing, just the `cout` checks and keep looping till it gives a segmentation fault @yanivx

Comment: Wanted to see what was the last output before going for a segmentation fault

Comment: @yanivx what you mean by output, cause when i test i key in rubbish value into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with an infinite loop because the error flags are not reset at the end of your iterations.

You should do a cin.clear() to reset the failbit before attempting any other operations:

```
if(cin.fail())
{
   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //skip bad input
   ...
}
```

On your second loop, you check if the vector of data is empty or not. If it is not empty (a second entry) and your data is new, it will fall indefinitely in the else statement that increases `countcheck`.

Two things may happen: an infinite loop or a segmentation fault (out of bounds exception).

You should check for an upperbound limit, e.g.:

```
if(countcheck > Vector.size())
{
    //This data is new
    PTD.setLD(LD);
    Vector.push_back (PTD);
    cout << "\nRecord stored successfully, returning back to main menu." << endl;
    exit = true;
}
else if(Vector[countcheck].getX() == MainX && 
    ...
}
```

You could also use a `for statement` instead:

```
for(countcheck = 0; countcheck  < Vector.size(); countcheck ++)
{
    if(Vector[countcheck].getX() == MainX && ...)
    {
        ...
        exit = true;
        break;
    }
}

//New element
if(countercheck == Vector.size())
{
    PTD.setLD(LD);
    Vector.push_back (PTD);
    cout << "\nRecord stored successfully, returning back to main menu." << endl;
    exit = true;
}
```

Comment: still the same, still goes into infinite loop

Comment: When you input a char instead of int does it still stuck?
Updating my answer about your second loop (have seen it just now).

Comment: any solution to solve the 2nd infinite loop ? I can't think of any ways to do it

Comment: ok i have manage to solve the first issue, i emptied out the stuff inside `cin.ignore` and just use `cin.ignore();`

Comment: Your infinite loop is probably on the else statement that I mentioned in my updated answer. It keeps incrementing countcheck, but you don't check for a upper limit, which should be Vector.size(). If the system does not complain about accessing an invalid memory position (segfault), then it will keep iterating and will never end.

Updating my answer.

Comment: I tried both, the while loop doesn't go into infinite loop anymore, it just give a segmentation fault straight away. For the for solution, it wouldn't even go into the for loop.

Comment: I might have placed some of the codes wrongly, after rearranging, i can store it once, check if there's any duplicate data and that's it. I can't store 2nd data

Comment: I added some `cout` to do some checking and realize, after inputting data and running the function another time, after the `for` loop, the `countcheck` will be **2**. Which i don't get it, it should stop and exit the loop once `countcheck` = 1.

Comment: My code with the for loop can actually substitute your second while() completely (eliminaying the need for a while). It will first check for duplicates in case the `Vector.size() > 0`. If any duplicate is found, it will break the for and countcheck will be less than Vector.size().  If `countcheck == Vector.size()`, a new element should be placed, because no duplicates were found.

My code lacks a check for Vector.empty() to insert the first element.

Comment: You are right. It should be equals to one. Do a ctrl+f do find where you are incrementing the variable

Comment: finally, i found the error, there was a `countcheck++` somewhere that i didn't notice, it works for `for` loop, thanks !